# "Web Services" Node is absent in GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.0.1

Tags: web-services, glassfish, glassfish-3

I can't see the "Web Services" Node (Menu Item in the Tree-like menu that GF admin console has on its left side) in glassfish's admin console.

Is there a way to enable it in glassfish? Should I download any upgrades for glassfish to enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answers: No and no.

Longer answer:

There have been a fair number of changes in the Admin Console between GlassFish Server 2.x and 3.x.

There is no explicit node in the tree in 3.x.  Most of the data that was available in the tree has been shifted into the pages associated with the app that implements the endpoint.

If you have an endpoint defined in a web application named WSI, you can find info about the endpoints on the pages that are associated with WSI.

Answer (score 1):

The special node "Web Services" was provided in order to perform web services management related tasks. (such as publish to registry, unpublish from registry, list registry locations, etc)

All web services management commands are not supported in 3.x release and thus the "Web Services" node. Don't know the exact reason why it was done.