# Java Web Service on Glassfish v3 using EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, glassfish-3

I  have a library which I would like to expose as a SOAP web service.

I am using GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 (build 12).

I have read the tutorial [here](http://developers.sun.com/appserver/reference/techart/ws_mgmt.html) and [here](http://www.jroller.com/raghukodali/entry/ejb_3_0_as_web) however these use an older version of Glassfish. Version 3 does not have a "Web Services" Node [as noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268018/web-services-node-is-absent-in-glassfish-server-open-source-edition-3-0-1), which makes the tutorials somewhat hard to follow.

I have created an annotated POJO (EJB) using a normal Eclipse project, exported it as a jar file and have deployed it. Glassfish shows this as a "Web Application". I am unsure how to access these as a web service. At what URL can I access the web methods I have created?

**Edit:**
Problems with using the generated WSDL are at: [Using GlassFish v3, EJB and SOAPUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487348/using-glassfish-v3-ejb-and-soapui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would acces the generated WSDL file in the same address where the service is deployed + `?wsdl` suffix. E.g. `http://localhost:8080/myapp/myservice?wsdl`

Then you can use tools like [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org) to create XML requests suitable for that WSDL.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations to generate the WSDL please? However note that my methods return user defined objects eg: class UserInfo {String user; String password;} , so any generation methods would also have to support returning such types. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: If everything went well during deployment, The WSDL gets automatically generated and you should be able to access it using the URL as I explained in my answer. Let me know if that works.

Comment: The WSDL was generated, you are correct, however when I tried to use it I found that it had not been generated correctly. I have specified this new problem in my question. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: your web service response seems to be empty. Have you debugged your code to make sure the web service operation is doing what you expect?

Comment: I have tested it as a "normal" Java SE method and it works perfectly. Shouldn't the translation to a web method just be the annotation? Thanks again.

Comment: In theory, yes. But I would debug the web service after deployed in order to make sure it is behaving as expected.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5788/discussion-between-et13-and-gonzalo-garcia-lasurtegui)

Answer (score 1):

> I am unsure how to access these as a web service. At what URL can I access the web methods I have created?

Your web server on deployment will pulish a WSDL and will give you URL to that WSDL file published. Now client can access the Webservices from using that WSDL

Comment: Thank you, you are correct, however a new problem has transpired, as explained in my edited question. I would appreciate your input. Thanks again.