# Using GlassFish v3, EJB and SOAPUI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, glassfish-3, soapui

I would like to create a web service.

I am using Glassfish v3, an Eclipse Dynamic Web Project, and SOAPUI to test.

I have the following code in eclipse:

Class MyLogin

```
package packageTest;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class MyLogin {

@WebMethod
public AuthInfo login(@WebParam(name = "email") String email,@WebParam(name = "password")String password) throws IOException, CustomException {     
    if(email == null || email.isEmpty()){
            throw new CustomException("Email cannot be empty.");
        }

        if(password == null || password.isEmpty()){
            throw new CustomException("Password cannot be empty.");
        }
        return new AuthInfo("auth","token");    
    }
}
```

Class AuthInfo

```
package packageTest;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class AuthInfo {

    private String token;
    private String auth;

    public AuthInfo(){}

    public AuthInfo(String auth,String token) {
        super();
        this.token = token;
        this.auth = auth;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }
    public String getAuth() {
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AuthInfo [auth=" + auth + ", token=" + token + "]";
    }

}
```

Class CustomException

```
package packageTest;

public class CustomException extends Exception {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomException() {
    }

    public CustomException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

    public CustomException(String msg,
            Throwable cause){
        super(msg,cause);
    }

}
```

Glassfish generates the WSDL.

I place the WSDL in SOAPUI and get this generated request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pac="http://packageTest/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <pac:login>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <email>email</email>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <password>password</password>
          </pac:login>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

and get the response:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:loginResponse xmlns:ns2="http://packageTest/">
         <return/>
      </ns2:loginResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

What is going wrong please? I suspect there is something wrong with the request I am sending, but there may be something wrong with the annotations as this is my first attempt at EJB web services.

I would expect an answer containing the Strings "auth" and "token" as returned by the web method login in class MyLogin.

Comment: I have added my expected response at the end, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see `@WebParam`

```
@WebMethod
public AuthInfo login(@WebParam(name = "email") String email, @WebParam(name = "password") String password) throws IOException, CustomException {
```

Try changing the signature like above and then try testing it using SOAPUI

**Update**

You also need to annotate your `AuthInfo` class  like,

```
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.NONE)
@Entity
public class AuthInfo{
    @XmlElement
    private String auth;

    @XmlElement
    private String token;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that was one problem, now the request is being generated by soap properly, but I get an empty response. Is there something I should do for the response object AuthInfo please?

Comment: Updated the answer hope  be that helps